# ASP.net hiding a div

Tags: asp.net

show a div having the labels for last date if in the database last date is not null else hide the div.
I need to hide this div

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">End Date:</label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="edate" runat="server" class="form-control">
        </asp:Label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How you are binding your label? You need it through Javascript or server side code? What you have tried? Your question is Unclear.

Comment: Could you please improve your question? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write up a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a `Panel`(rendered as div) or  make it `runat="server"`, then you can use the `Visible` property. If a control is `Visible=false` it won't be rendered at all at client-side:

```
<div class="form-group" runat="server" ID="FormDiv" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">End Date:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="edate" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that a server-control also needs an ID.

in codebehind:

```
FormDiv.Visible = dbLastDate != DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: if it isn't  a Nullable<DateTime>   variable is taking the value {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}